# how can an adjective function as an adverb

Tags: adjectives, adverbs

Yet because the immediate effect of the medicine is to make the patient feel rapidly better and she is not told what might happen later,she goes home happy.

In the last half of this sentence ，the “happy”is used kind of like “happily”，but how can it be used this way？in what situation and in what way，an adjective can be put at the end of a sentence this way？

Comment: The word "happy" is not modifying "goes" it is modifying "she". In other words it is an adjective describing the patient's state of mind. There is, actually, a comma missing from the text; the whole passage from "because" to "later" is parenthetical so the main part of the sentence  is "Yet she goes home happy." This makes it much clearer that the adjective refers to the woman.

Comment: when can an adjective be put at the end of a sentence when the meaning and grammatical structure of the sentence is already complete even without it？

Answer (score 2):

From a comment by [BoldBen](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/191850/boldben)...

The word "happy" is not modifying "goes" it is modifying "she". In other words it is an adjective describing the patient's state of mind. There is, actually, a comma missing from the text; the whole passage from "because" to "later" is parenthetical so the main part of the sentence is "Yet she goes home happy." This makes it much clearer that the adjective refers to the woman.

Comment: To expand on the difference in meaning, she is happy when she goes home; she is not necessarily going home in a happy way (e.g. skipping down the street).

Comment: when can an adjective be put at the end of a sentence when the meaning and grammatical structure of the sentence is already complete even without it？

Comment: It's not complete. Yes, she goes home; but the adjective describes her on her way home.

Comment: by analogy，is it OK to write sentences like He killed that person scared 、I'm talking to you interested、or I slept anxious ？there must be problems that English learner meet during the learning journey but that doesnt make sense to native speakers. just don't mind this～

Comment: Aha. No. Your last comment merits a question all of its own.